# How to add greater than/less than to Hibernate filters

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, filter

How can you add greater than or less than symbols to the condition on a Hibernate filter specified in the hbm.xml file?

I am trying to add a filter to limit the collection to a specific date range:

```
<filter name="limitTalksByDateRange" condition="talkstart >= :tstart and talkstart <= :tend" />
```

Unfortunately this breaks the XML parsing. I've tried backslash-escaping, "ge" and "le" and even "between :tstart and :tend" which is mentioned in the Hibernate documentation. None has worked, and I'll be damned if I can find any documentation whatsoever that specifically delineates the valid operators in the filter condition.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
<filter name="limitTalksByDateRange" condition="talkstart &gt;= :tstart and talkstart &lt;= :tend" />
```

Note the `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of the `>` and `<`.

Also, the [examples](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/filters.html) that I saw did not have the '`:`' on the limit variables, so perhaps this:

```
<filter name="limitTalksByDateRange" condition="talkstart &gt;= tstart and talkstart &lt;= tend" />
```

or this:

```
<filter name="limitTalksByDateRange" condition="talkstart BETWEEN tstart and tend" />
```

would work better.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this works:

```
<filter name="limitTalksByDaterange" condition="talkstart &#62;= :tstart and talkstart &#60;= :tend" />
```

I think the #nn codes might be a bit more reliable; I've seen &gt and &lt break in certain contexts.

I wasn't able to make the between construct work at all.